# Stray Formatting of Last Row of Table using Kable and collapse_rows in R Markdown

Tags: r, kable

I'm fairly new to R programming and I'm hoping that there's a kable expert out there that can help me out.  I have the following code in an R markdown document:

```
test_table <- data.frame(column_1=c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
                         column_2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                         column_3=c(0,9,8,7,6,5))
test_table %>%
  kable(caption = "test_table*", table.attr = "style='width:95%;'" ) %>% 
  kable_classic(full_width = T, position = "center", ) %>% 

 

  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle") %>% 
  # center and add horizontal lines to all rows
  row_spec(c(1:(nrow(test_table)-1)),
           align = "c",
           extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px dotted #c5c5c5; vertical-align: middle") %>% 
  # format header row
  row_spec(0,
           color = "#000000",
           background = "#93d500",
           align = "c",
           extra_css = "border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle") %>% 
  # format last row
    row_spec(nrow(test_table),
             align = "c",
             extra_css = "border-bottom: 3px solid #93d500; vertical-align: middle") %>%  
  footnote(symbol = "test_table",
           symbol_manual = '*',
           footnote_as_chunk =  T)
```

The problem is that the final row in the first column is not getting the green line that the rest of the table has, but instead has either dots or a black line like the following picture:

[image]

Is there any way I can get the green line to show in the first column without getting rid of my collapse_rows clause?

Comment: I get a complete green line for all the columns. I don't have any black line as shown in your picture.

Comment: I wonder if this might be a version issue.  I'm currently constrained by my project to use R 3.4.3.

Comment: I am on R 4.0.3